Godot4: Jitter when moving camera over tileset map
I currently develop a game where the player moves a camera over a tilemap map to navigate. Unfortunatley as shown in the video below, the textures look weird when the camera is moving and I don’t know how to make them look sharp.
video: https://www.loom.com/share/f98c47207a0b4dcaaeae621ef1b028d9?sid=a6128b25-aa58-43ce-a140-26a17a07b743
Code of camera scene:
extends Camera2D

# Zoom variables
var min_zoom = Vector2(1, 1)
var max_zoom = Vector2(2, 2)
var desired_zoom = zoom
# Movement variables
var camera_speed = 500
# Map boundaries
var min_x_pos = 0
var max_x_pos = 2560
var min_y_pos = 0
var max_y_pos = 1360


func _physics_process(delta):
    if global_position != get_camera_position(delta):
        global_position = get_camera_position(delta)
#       var tween = create_tween()
#       tween.tween_property(self, "global_position", get_camera_position(delta), .2)


func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("zoom_in"):
        desired_zoom = zoom + Vector2(.25, .25)
        if desired_zoom <= max_zoom and desired_zoom >= min_zoom:
            var tween = create_tween()
            tween.tween_property(self, "zoom", desired_zoom, .08)
    elif event.is_action_pressed("zoom_out"):
        desired_zoom = zoom - Vector2(.25, .25)
        if desired_zoom <= max_zoom and desired_zoom >= min_zoom:
            var tween = create_tween()
            tween.tween_property(self, "zoom", desired_zoom, .08)


func get_camera_position(delta):
    var new_camera_position = global_position
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right") and new_camera_position.x <= 1984:
        new_camera_position.x += camera_speed * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left") and new_camera_position.x >= 400:
        new_camera_position.x -= camera_speed * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up") and new_camera_position.y >= 292:
        new_camera_position.y -= camera_speed * delta
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down") and new_camera_position.y <= 1068:
        new_camera_position.y += camera_speed * delta
    return new_camera_position



did you already tried to move the camera without the tween?

yes, I already tried that. It doesn't really change anything. Could limiting the cameras movement to full pixel values solve the issue? Unfortunatley I don't know how to implement that.

I don't really know how I fixed it, but the jitter is gone now. I just played around with position snapping and the position smoothing option of the camera. I know have position smoothing toggled on and it is working perfectly.
